# Conditional formatting formula wont drag down

Tags: excel, formula, conditional-formatting

ive made conditonal formatting so when my Priority column is not blank then highlight the whole row pink.
[image]

now when i try and drag this down it wont work.
it just changed the formula
[image]

I need to go down to line 10,000

Comment: Then change the applies to to `=$A$3:$J$10000,$L$3:L$10000` and the formula to `=$L3<>""`